# Corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, deb, dpkg

I'm trying to compile and install an open source application on Ubuntu.  I can make the application, make the installer, and make the package.  I don't see any error during those steps.  when I issue the dpkg -i to install it if fails with the following error.

dpkg: error processing archive application.deb (--install):
 corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

I can only find references to fixing the issue when downloading files and say to issue apt-get clean and purge.  I've done that and it doesn't work and it doesn't seem applicable since I'm creating the install file. When I issue dpkg -c application.deb, it shows me the contents, so the file isn't total corrupted.

Any suggestions on how to get this application to install?

Comment: You can use the dpkg-deb command to examine the .deb file further. What application are you trying to build a package for? Maybe the problem is easier to spot for someone trying to redo your steps.

Comment: It is Brewtarget.  https://github.com/Brewtarget/brewtarget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the description on https://github.com/Brewtarget/brewtarget on a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 gives me a .deb that installs.

These are the commands I ran:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cmake git qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins doxygen
$ git clone https://github.com/Brewtarget/brewtarget.git
$ mkdir brewtarget-build
$ cd brewtarget-build
$ cmake ../brewtarget
$ make
$ make package
$ sudo apt-get install libphonon4 libqt4-webkit phonon phonon-backend-vlc
$ sudo dpkg -i brewtarget*.deb
Selecting previously unselected package brewtarget_2.2.0.
(Reading database ... 175209 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brewtarget_2.2.0_x86_64.deb ...
Unpacking brewtarget_2.2.0 (2.2.0-1) ...
Setting up brewtarget_2.2.0 (2.2.0-1) ...
$ file *.deb
brewtarget_2.2.0_x86_64.deb: Debian binary package (format 2.0)
```

What version of Ubuntu are you running?

It is odd that your error message says "application.deb", as I got a .deb named "brewtarget_2.2.0_x86_64.deb" when following the instructions.

Comment: Thanks.  Those instructions get me something that will install.  Won't run yet, so I'm working on the next step.  I did get a brewtarget_2.2.0_x86_64.deb.  I was initially making a generic questions.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: So what did you do different at first? I just followed the Brewtarget instructions.

Comment: I was following the instructions at https://github.com/Brewtarget/brewtarget.   $ sudo apt-get install libphonon4 libqt4-webkit phonon phonon-backend-vlc was not part of those instructions so at this point I'm assuming that was the difference.  I need to do some additional research.

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands

```
# sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite application.deb
```

After that run

```
# sudo apt-get -f install
```